# How to configure Mozilla Thunderbird to read email from Microsoft Exchange?

Tags: thunderbird, exchange

**How** can I connect Mozilla Thunderbird to read email from a Microsoft Exchange server?

I have the address for Exchange server. Thunderbird asks for IMAP and SMTP server addresses. What do I put?

---

Hey! Neither of those supposed duplicates answers my question **how**.

[image]

Comment: Possible dup of http://superuser.com/questions/353153/does-thunderbird-work-with-exchange-account and http://superuser.com/questions/77241/connecting-thunderbird-with-exchange-native-protocol

Comment: It [may or may not be possible](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MAPI_Support).

Answer (score 1):

1. Setup a new account under Tools/Account Settings/Add Account…
   Select “E-mail Account” and add your details.
   Use IMAP and input your incoming exchange server (Try port 993 and SSL encryption).
2. Subscribe to all required folders by right clicking on the account name and choosing ‘Subscribe…’.
3. Change the trash folder’s name to ‘Deleted Items’:
4. Go to Tools/Options/Advanced/Config Editor:
   Set boolean mail.check_all_imap_folders_for_new to true.
   Set boolean mail.imap.expunge_after_delete to true.
5. Go to Tools/Account Settings for the IMAP account:
   Have it place a copy of sent mail to the ‘Sent Items’ folder.
   Also have it save drafts and templates in the ‘Drafts’ folder.
   Go to Junk Settings and have it send all junk to ‘Junk E-mail’.
6. If you are not using the Thunderbird default SMTP server, go to Tools/Account Settings/Outgoing Server and configure your outgoing SMTP server.

As per http://fourforces.wordpress.com/2008/02/04/setup-mozilla-thunderbird-to-work-with-microsoft-exchange-server/

Comment: I have Thunderbird 15, the add account wizard looks very different to that blog.