# How to see received email using ExQuilla

Tags: email, thunderbird, exchange

After IMAP support was removed from my school email, I found and installed ExQuilla for Thunderbird on my Windows 10 computer. It looks like it's working for sending messages, but I don't see any folder for the account; it looks as if I can't read any received messages on Thunderbird.

Is there something I need to do to create the folders?

(Not sure how relevant this is, but I backed up all messages I received by IMAP, and I'm pretty sure they're also still in the Thunderbird\Profiles folder.)

Comment: I am aware that, if you *only* look at the titles, this looks like it might be a duplicate of [How to configure...](https://superuser.com/questions/477090/how-to-configure-mozilla-thunderbird-to-read-email-from-microsoft-exchange), but if you actually read what is asked there, it's different. If the people who marked it a duplicate of a couple other questions had done similarly, I think they would have found the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably not that you have no folders, but that the folders you are seeing are only your Favorite folders. New folders are not automatically given Favorite status.

If you don't see anything on the top of the folders pane about Favorites or All or anything, click the View menu, click Folders, and click All. Then right-click the folders you want to always see and check Favorite on them, if that's your way.

(If you want to see Favorites but have it easy to check other views, like All, click View, Toolbars, Folder Pane Toolbar.)